# How change the embeded data to be "flat" in a dataframe.

Tags: r

Here below  is the code:

```
 exam.d <- data.frame(seq.no=c(2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4),
                          pd.no=c(100,100,100,200,200,200,300,300,300,400,400,400),
                          value=100:111)

  f <- function(a){
    a/(a[1]+a[2])*2
  }

  d <- aggregate(value~pd.no,data=exam.d, f)

> d
  pd.no   value.1   value.2   value.3
1   100 0.9950249 1.0049751 1.0149254
2   200 0.9951691 1.0048309 1.0144928
3   300 0.9953052 1.0046948 1.0140845
4   400 0.9954338 1.0045662 1.0136986
```

So I want to melt the d to enable further work, but I got a error message:

```
> melt(d, id="pd.no")
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  dims [product 12] do not match the length of object [4]
```

I checked the d's information, then I know why. The Value1, value2, value3 is not a "real" element in d's dataframe, but a so called "value" is:

```
> str(d)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ pd.no: num  100 200 300 400
 $ value: num [1:4, 1:3] 0.995 0.995 0.995 0.995 1.005 ...
```

To solve my problem I can bypass the situation by use d$value. But I want to know, if I want to get a dataframe like this without "value" and can get the data by d$value1, d$value2... , how to do that?

```
> d
  pd.no   value.1   value.2   value.3
1   100 0.9950249 1.0049751 1.0149254
2   200 0.9951691 1.0048309 1.0144928
3   300 0.9953052 1.0046948 1.0140845
4   400 0.9954338 1.0045662 1.0136986
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert that interior matrix to individual columns using:

```
do.call(data.frame, d)
##   pd.no   value.1  value.2  value.3
## 1   100 0.9950249 1.004975 1.014925
## 2   200 0.9951691 1.004831 1.014493
## 3   300 0.9953052 1.004695 1.014085
## 4   400 0.9954338 1.004566 1.013699
```

Thus, if you wanted to `melt` the data, try:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(do.call(data.frame, d), "pd.no")
```

Comment: Thank u. It works well. But could you tell me what the difference between "data.frame(d)" and "do.call(data.frame, d)", since the first can not work but the second can?

Comment: @kanpu, what you actually want to do is `data.frame(d$value)`. The `do.call(data.frame, d)` approach is a generalization across all the values. This could be useful if you were aggregating more than one column.

Comment: Thank you. It is very helpful.